# Clang ast-dump results in infinite loop

Tags: c++, c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

For some reason when I try to get the ast-dump of any C/C++ code with Clang, I get an infinite loop which eventually results in `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1136` or some similar error code.

I'm running Windows 10 with Clang version 13.0 (Also tried Clang 12.0 with same issues). I run the command `clang -Xclang -ast-dump filename.c`.

I've tried multiple files, but at this point I'm just trying to get a hello world ast (which compiles and runs fine via clang).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop if it terminates. :-)

The dumped AST includes `stdio.h`, which you included, so it's quite big (about 800 lines, when I tried it).

The error message is because the clang compiler (`cc1`) does not produce an object file when you pass it the `-ast-dump` option, but the clang driver (`clang`) doesn't know that. The driver is expecting to be able to link the generated object file into an executable, but it doesn't find the object file so it complains.

Use

```sh
clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only filename.c
```

to terminate the driver after the AST has been dumped.

Comment: Thanks! Although I had to change -x to -Xclang for it to work. It's working, but It still is printing the ast for stdio.h, is that expected? Is there any way to ignore include files for ast purposes?

Comment: @Zami77: sorry about the missing word; I fixed it.

Comment: @Zami77: in C, the semantics of `#include` are essentially the same as copying the included file into the source at that point. So the AST includes the entire input. If you need more control over how an AST is printed, you could write a tool using the clang library. But the might be more effort than you want to devote to this problem.

Comment: Yea, I figured the include would be included no matter what. I appreciate all your effort, it's been very helpful!